# Trying to get different time for different button from time picker

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am creating a application in android, time picker for getting time for each button click,show different time but it`s same time for all button.... help me out.
i have created three number picker after that from timer picker i am trying to get time for different button click with different time should show.

MainActivity file

```
public class MainA ctivity extends Activity {
private TextView Prepare;
int timeMinute1,timeSecond1;
Button btnSelectPrepare,btnSelectWork,btnSelectRest;
public  int hour1,hour2,hour3,hour4,hour5,minute1,minute2,minute3,minute4,minute5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    updateViews();
       btnSelectPrepare=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectPrepare);
        btnSelectWork=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectWork);
        btnSelectRest=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectRest);
        btnSelectCycles=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectCycles);
        btnSelectSets=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectSets);
        btnSelectStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectStart);

    btnSelectStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("timeMinute",timeMinute1);
        i.putExtra("timeSecond",timeSecond1);
        startActivity(i);

        }});

    }

private void updateViews(){
    Prepare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectPrepare);
    TextView Work = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectWork);
    //Rest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectRest);
}

public void showPicker(View v){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    MyTimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new MyTimePickerDialog(this, new MyTimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int seconds) {
            timeMinute1=minute;
            timeSecond1=seconds;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Prepare.setText(getString(R.string.time) + String.format("%02d", hourOfDay)+
                    ":" + String.format("%02d", minute) + 
                    ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));              
            btnSelectWork.setText(getString(R.string.time) + String.format("%02d", hourOfDay)+
                    ":" + String.format("%02d", minute) + 
                    ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));              

        }

        public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view,
                int hourOfDay, int minute, int seconds) {
             minute1 = minute;

             System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
             System.out.println("minute1"+timeMinute1);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), now.get(Calendar.SECOND), true);
    mTimePicker.show();     
}
public void showPicker1(View v){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    MyTimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new MyTimePickerDialog(this, new MyTimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDayy, int minutee, int secondss) {
            timeMinute1=minutee;
            timeSecond1=secondss;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            btnSelectWork.setText(getString(R.string.time1) + String.format("%02d", hourOfDayy)+
                    ":" + String.format("%02d", minutee) + 
                    ":" + String.format("%02d", secondss));             

        }

        public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view,
                int hourOfDay, int minute, int seconds) {
             minute1 = minute;

             System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
             System.out.println("minute1"+timeMinute1);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), now.get(Calendar.SECOND), true);
    mTimePicker.show();     
}
```

Comment: please let me now if any one have the solution,it`s very urgent.......